# Getting device network urls calls

Tags: android, wireshark, network-protocols

I'm trying to build an application that gives the user statistics about his network usage,

From 3G/Wifi surfing to application network usage.

The main important data I'm looking for, are the urls of the network calls.

I have next code, to find the browser history:

```
private void getBrowserHistory()
{
    String[] proj = new String[]{Browser.BookmarkColumns.TITLE, Browser.BookmarkColumns.URL};
    String sel = Browser.BookmarkColumns.BOOKMARK + " = 0"; // 0 = history, 1 = bookmark
    Cursor mCur = this.managedQuery(Browser.BOOKMARKS_URI, proj, sel, null, null);
    this.startManagingCursor(mCur);
    mCur.moveToFirst();

    if (mCur.moveToFirst() && mCur.getCount() > 0)
    {
        while (mCur.isAfterLast() == false)
        {
            String title = mCur.getString(mCur.getColumnIndex(Browser.BookmarkColumns.TITLE));
            String url = mCur.getString(mCur.getColumnIndex(Browser.BookmarkColumns.URL));
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Site title: " + title);
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Site url: " + url);
            mCur.moveToNext();
        }
    }
}
```

But to find the applications network usage I need something more like [WireShark](http://www.wireshark.org/)

I assume final solution for that issue is complicated, but any advice would be welcome.

Answer (score 2):

If, like you said, you are dealing with a **rooted device**, you can set your monitoring application as the default *system proxy*.

This way, by acting as a [transparent proxy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server#Transparent_proxy), you will be able to detect the ingoing and outgoing connections.

**Where do I start?**

If you want to take a look at a possible implementation, you can try with [ProxyDroid](https://github.com/madeye/proxydroid), which is open-source and definitely a good starting point.

**What you should do**

What you need to do is trigger some `iptables` commands in order to set your application as the system proxy: [here](https://github.com/madeye/proxydroid/blob/master/src/org/proxydroid/ProxyDroidService.java) you can see how ProxyDroid does that.

Your application will then listen for connection requests, execute them and send the responses accordingly: again, [this](http://android-er.blogspot.it/2011/01/implement-simple-socket-server-in.html) is a very basic example of how the whole thing works at your application's side.

Comment: Can you add more explanation to your solution?

Comment: I've added some more details about what you should do ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can't achieve what you want on a non-rooted device.

(There is a Wireshark equivalent app in the Play Store already for rooted devices called [Shark for root](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=lv.n3o.shark)).

By the way, your code to read the browser history only gets history from the default Android browser.  If the user runs an alternative browser, such as Firefox, then it doesn't use the same database, so its history will not appear there.

Comment: I'm working on rooted device. And I know wireshark app, what I want to know is how did they know to catch the network data/usage

Answer (score 1):

My answer is a bit vague and I apologise in advance BUT have you considered setting up a local vpn on the device. This is how [noroot firewall](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=app.greyshirts.firewall). This would allow you to see all the data flowing in and out of the device. Only cavat is that the user would not be able to use any other vpn (ie they couldnt vpn to work, or use noroot firewall)